# Should I use a hash for user-specific data in Redis, and if so, how?

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis and I’m trying to work out which data type is right to store a set of data specific to one user.

The data set would be specific to, say, user 1000 and therefore I might call the type

```
1000:MatchesMembers
```

The data type would then hold a list of other users like:

```
1001, photo, age, name, location, city, country
1003, photo, age, name, location, city, country
1007, photo, age, name, location, city, country
1009, photo, age, name, location, city, country
```

I have read that hash types are the best to use if possible - [Redis set vs hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557075/redis-set-vs-hash)

If the hash is the best to use, is this how I use it?

```
var hash = client.GetHash<string>("1000:MatchesMembers");
hash.SetValue("key", "value");
```

Do I have to set each value individually or can they be set in bulk?

Finally is it possible to pop values out of the hash? I will take around 10 entries each time and would like to remove them once I use them. Is there a way to pop entries off the hash or do I need to read and delete? Would a different data type better suit this functionality?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer to the syntax question, as you did not say which redis driver you are using.
So here are information based on Redis commands.

Use [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) to set all data related to a given user.

```
HMSET 1001 photo "url of the photo" age 31 name "user name" location "location name" city "city name" country "country name"
```

Use a set to store the Ids of the users

```
SADD 1000:MatchesMembers 1001 1003 1007 1009
```

To remove a user from the Set use [SREM](http://redis.io/commands/srem)

To optimize the insertion of multiple member profiles, use [pipeling](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining). Your Redis driver should handle it.